# Initialize static array of template class with derived class type

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, initialization, multiple-inheritance

I have a program with a main function that simply prints a string. When I run this program it crashed without output in the console. I found out the problem happens when I insert an element into the map of OperatorCore (symbolMap).

This is the minimal code:

```
//Binary.hpp
class Binary final : public OperatorCore, public StaticPool<Binary> {
public:
    Binary(int ID, std::string name)
        : OperatorCore(name), StaticPool<Binary>(ID) {
    }
    ~Binary() {}
};
//Binary.cpp
template<>
const Binary StaticPool<Binary>::pool[] = {
    Binary(0, "a string value")//without this line of code, it prints works
};

//OperatorCore.hpp
class OperatorCore {
public:
    static std::map<std::string, OperatorCore*> symbolMap;
    const std::string name;
    OperatorCore (std::string name);
    virtual ~OperatorCore () {}
};
//OperatorCore.cpp
std::map<std::string, OperatorCore*> OperatorCore::symbolMap{};
OperatorCore::OperatorCore(std::string name) : name(name) {
    symbolMap.insert({name, this});
}


//StaticPool
template<typename T, typename TKey = int>
class StaticPool {
public:
    const TKey ID;
    static const T pool[];
    StaticPool(TKey ID) : ID(ID) {}
    virtual ~StaticPool() {}
};
```

The problem does not occur if I delete one of the highlighted lines. Does this design cause a memory corruption?

**EDIT**: The initialization of `OperatorCore::symbolMap` is in the same file where is also the implementation of OperatorCore constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have an order-of-initialization problem. In other words, your program tries to initialize `pool` before `symbolMap`, and the constructor of the `Binary` object calls the base constructor, which tries to use `symbolMap`, which hasn't been constructed yet.

There are a number of solutions for this. Your best bet is probably to turn the `symbolMap` static member into a static variable inside a special getter function:

```
class OperatorCore {
public:
    static std::map<std::string, OperatorCore*>& symbolMap() {
        static std::map<std::string, OperatorCore*> instance;
        return instance;
    }
};
```

Comment: The initialization of symbolMap and the implementation of the OperatorCore's constructor are ine same .cpp file.

Comment: The code for `OperatorCore`'s constructor is irrelevant. What matters is that the definitions of `OperatorCore::symbolMap` and `StaticPool<Binary>::pool` are in different files.

Answer (score 1):

You have a case of [`static initialization order fiasco`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order-on-first-use.html). Meaning that your statics might be constructed in the wrong order. I do not know if initializing the static objects in **the same file** in the correct order works. But otherwise you should delay the initialization of the pool which depends on the map. Maybe write a function to initialize the pool and call it at the start of your `main`.

Comment: Yes, I edited the question. The initialization is in the same file cpp file where is also che OperatorCore constructor body.
`std::map<std::string, OperatorCore*> OperatorCore::symbolMap{};`

Comment: @biowep: please correct the constructor name as well, and show the initialization, so we can see the order. Another idea would be to initialize the pool from a function, but that is if the before part fails. Maybe supply a complete MWE (with a main function)

Comment: @biowep: by the way it looks like you are using cpp11, you should be able to inline initialize the static members.

Comment: if I do so, I get an error: `in-class initialization of static data member 'std::map<std::basic_string<char>, OperatorCore*> OperatorCore::symbolMap' of incomplete type`

Comment: @biowep: `class x { static templateType<x*> y={} }` has no other choice than giving you the above error unless you give a forward declaration. But your problem is elsewhere, you have a `static initialization order fiasco`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. OperatorCore* is not a template type.
BTW, the error name is usefull, now I know what to search to find more information.

Comment: @biowep what i mean is that `std::map` is a template type, and in your case it depends on `OperatorCore`. Since `OperatorCore`'s definition is currently parsed the type of it is not yet known unless you put a forward declaration (`class OperatorCore;`) before it.